# Exception using Charts from Silverlight toolkit 4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

I am getting this runtime exception :

**FileNotFoundException - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

while trying to use "Charts" in my silverlight 4 application.
Reference to System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit is already there in the project.

I've reinstalled Silverlight toolkit 4 (April) but it doesn't solve problem. Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the "Local Copy" assembly reference property for System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the reference and re-adding it.  If the reinstall of the toolkit did tidy things up then perhaps the reference itself needs tidying up to.